# Get context of the active object

Tags: python

I am writing a addon that shows the currently available shourtcut keys.

At the moment I am filtering the availalble shortcuts via the bpy.context region and space data and comparing those to the settings for each shortcut. 
I then poll each one to see if it can be called in the current context. 
After all this I am still getting shortcuts in the list that are not actually relevant to the current context. 
I am thinking this is because the active object is in a different scope/context which the C code is filtering out but I can't work out how to do this filtering.

If I could find which space the active object is in and if that was the same as the current space then show those shortcuts otherwise don't.
I can't seem to find out how to find the context of the active object rather than just the current context.
I hope I have been clear enough here.

Thanks

Yardie

Comment: There is the concept of an active object, and of selected objects - but current context and context of active object is identical IMO. When we say "context", it's not just about the active object however. It is also the space the mouse is over, how certain properties are set and so on. What exactly do you want to know / access?

Comment: The problem with this is however the active object is still the active object when the context is changed to a different space. Also for some reason poll() is returning positive for some things even when the operator shouldn't and can't be run.

Comment: `if idname and eval("bpy.ops.{:}.poll()".format(idname)):` is not failing as it should - then maybe that is my problem and that's not the right way to do this. It does seem to be the way that the C code works.

Comment: Thank you CoDEmanX all your help has finally paid off. I think I have an idea of how to do the addon in a Blender UI way. You have clarified many things now all I have to work out is how to add an icon with my addon.

Comment: Operators may `return {'CANCELLED'}` or `{'PASS_THROUGH'}` to terminate execution after `poll()` returned `True`, which is sometimes necessary, as you can't access everything from the class method `poll()` or the conditions are too manifold to check in advance. You can't rely on `poll()` only, and not all operators have one anyway.

Comment: Yeah I don't like eval and was trying to think of an alternate. I think I'll go back to the C and do a bit more research. I was wondering why this hadn't been done but now I am getting to know why. Doesn't seem to be that popular idea and it's a lot of digging around.